# Como fazer um método dinâmico?

Tags: php

Tenho dois métodos um loadById e loadByCpf, gostaria de criar um único método, ex: loadCliente, como faço?

```php
public function loadByCpf($cpfcust)
        {
            $sql = new Sql();
            $results = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_custumer WHERE cpfcust = :cpfcust", array(
                ":cpfcust"=>$cpfcust
            ));
}

public function loadById($idcust)
        {
            $sql = new Sql();
            $results = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_custumer WHERE idcust = :idcust", array(
                ":idcust"=>$idcust
            ));
}
```

Comment: O que já tentou? Que problema teve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar apenas um método que usa interpolação. Segue o exemplo:

```
    public function loadBy($key, $withValue)
    {

        $bind = ":{$key}";

        $sql = new Sql();
        $results = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_custumer WHERE {$key} = {$bind}", array(
            $bind => $withValue
        ));

    }
```

E apenas chamar o método na sua classe:

```
$this->loadBy('idcust', 10);
```

Ou você ainda pode criar um mẽtodo mais eficiente utilizando o método mégico _ _ call_ _

```
public function __call__($name, $arguments)
{

    if(strpos($name, 'loadBy') !== FALSE){
        $key = strtolower(str_replace('loadBy', '', $name));
        $this->loadBy($key, $arguments);
    }

}
```

E na sua função chamar

```
$this->loadByCpf(10);
$this->loadByName('John Doe');
$this->loaderEmail('john@doe.com');
```

Porém você precisar sempre tomar cuidado e prestar atenção se está passando os parâmetros corretos de acordo com o nome dos campos na sua tabela.